# Calculate percentage change of price based on Category with SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, price

I am writing a Query with SQL and couldn't figure it out yet...

My table looks like this:

```
Category Price Date
Cat1       20   2019-04
Cat2       12   2019-04
Cat3        5   2019-04
Cat1       23   2020-04
Cat2       17   2020-04
Cat3        8   2020-04
```

I would like to get a table that shows this:

```
Cat  Pct_change Period
Cat 1   0.15     2019-2020
Cat 2   0.41       "
```

And so on.

I can get this category by category but I have like 100 categories, cant do this manually. It would be great, too, to see both prices side by side. What I don't (can't) allow is to generate new tables just saving the data to join separate tables...

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEAD()` window function to get the price and date of the next date for each category:

```
SELECT Category,
       ROUND(1.0 * next_price / Price - 1, 2) Pct_change,
       SUBSTR(Date, 1, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(next_date, 1, 4) Period
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         LEAD(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Date) next_price,
         LEAD(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Date) next_date
  FROM tablename
)
WHERE next_date IS NOT NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=939c6296941f00dc0f2e812f1b8f2f62).
Results:

| Category | Pct_change | Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat1 | 0.15 | 2019-2020 |
| Cat2 | 0.42 | 2019-2020 |
| Cat3 | 0.6 | 2019-2020 |

Comment: Thank you very much! I got excatly what I was expecting!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first_value()`:

```
select distinct category, min(date), max(date),
       (-1 + first_value(price) over (partition by category order by date desc) /
         first_value(price) over (partition by category order by date asc)
       ) as percent_change
from t;
```